# cannot open 'libhunspell.lib' when trying to install hunspell for python

Tags: python, pip, hunspell

Im trying to install the ‘hunspell’ package for python 3.4 in windows 7 using pip,

but when running this

```
pip install hunspell
```

I get the following error message:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libhunspell.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

I tried to download and compile hunspell myself with Cygwin as was suggested in a similar question i found here:

[pip install hunspell: Cannot open include file: 'hunspell.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642034/pip-install-hunspell-cannot-open-include-file-hunspell-h-no-such-file-or-di)

but it didn’t help.

Comment: Try to search for the error code (1181), hope that will help you.

Comment: thanks, but the error code specifies that a certain file is missing, and in this case 'libhunspell.lib'. I still don't know what to do in order to resolve this.