# How do I install hunspell python package?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

When I try using pip,
pip install hunspell

I get an error:

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

According to this page, the author of the package does not know how to install it using conda environment:

https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell/issues/50

I will prefer to continue with conda instead of switching back to "regular" python distribution.

Comment: Can you please show more of the traceback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conda environment is no different. I used the same commands and it worked same as "regular" python installation.

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-dev 
sudo apt-get install libhunspell-dev
sudo pip install hunspell
```

Comment: May also need this apt-get install --reinstall --yes build-essential or that apt-get install --yes python3-dev

Answer (score 1):

To get `gcc`, on Ubuntu:

`sudo apt install build-essentials`

I would suggest using the package [CyHunspell](https://github.com/MSeal/cython_hunspell) which is regularly maintained:

`pip install cyhunspell` (currently not available via conda repositories)

It appears that [PyHunspell](https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell) (`pip install hunspell` or `conda install hunspell`) is no longer maintained, last commit 2 years ago, and very hacky to get working.