# How to use Hunspell in GitHub Actions

Tags: ubuntu, github, github-actions, hunspell

I made a pull request at GitHub ([isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines#1688](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/pull/1688)) to replace Travis CI with GitHub Actions.
Currently, the repository has [Hunspell](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell) configured using Travis CI, but it doesn't [work](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/runs/1196453940#step:3:36) in GitHub Actions.

It all works fine except for [Hunspell](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell). I have tried several ways to integrate it with GitHub Actions. Those are:

1. Add (in workflow file)

```yaml
env:
 apt: hunspell
```

Didn't work.

2. Add (in workflow file)

```yaml
env:
 SPELLCHECKER_PREFER_HUNSPELL: true
```

Didn't work either.

3. Install Hunspell separately in another command using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029568/how-do-i-install-hunspell-python-package).

Didn't work either.

Do you have any ideas why it isn't working?
Or how to make it work/implement it in GitHub Actions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Install hunspell before using it. Add `run: sudo apt-get install hunspell`. Init `apt` variable by hunspell string won't work.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly. 