# Problem with installing Python hunspell library

Tags: python, hunspell

I have already installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Build Tools. However, I am still encountering issues, and I have also attempted to install an older version of Hunspell, but that hasn't resolved the problem either.

`pip install hunspell`

```
Collecting hunspell
  Using cached hunspell-0.5.5.tar.gz (34 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: hunspell
  Building wheel for hunspell (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'hunspell' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHUNSPELL_STATIC 
-IV:/hunspell-1.3.3/src/hunspell -IC:\Users\PCP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\PCP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include "-IC:\Program Fil2\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tphunspell.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\hunspell.obj /MT
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
      hunspell.cpp
      hunspell.cpp(20): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'hunspell.hxx': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2    
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for hunspell
  Running setup.py clean for hunspell
Failed to build hunspell
ERROR: Could not build wheels for hunspell, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: See if this can solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642034/pip-install-hunspell-cannot-open-include-file-hunspell-h-no-such-file-or-di

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.